# I was redirected to an infected site, what should I do?

Tags: virus, url

I always avoid suspicious links, but recently, in one of my google searches, I clicked the first link on google (looked just a normal site), but it immediately redirected me to a weird news site (the news was basically "How I won $$, blablabla"), with a very weird URL. I heard a strange 'bip' after entering the site and immediately closed it (the site brings that window asking to close or leave, btw), then I copied the link in the browsing history and cleared the data (cookies, etc). I tried to access the same link I clicked on google and it didn't redirect me again; it entered in the site I was supposed to access.

I use Firefox as my browser, and smart https and ublock origin (advanced mode) as privacy extensions, and Bitdefender free as antivirus. None detected anything weird, so the bip came from the site.

I scanned the URL in VirusTotal and according to it the site is infected with "Fortinet" and "Spamhaus"

Can this have infected me somehow? I'm currently running a virus scan with BitDefender.

What else should I do?

Later I tried accessing it again in a portable browser with ublock and noscript, and it also redirected to a fake google site with a survey, but this time I was not logged in to my email.

Comment: Highly probable nothing happens. Many fraudulent ads page will pop out a beep, to get the user attention, "hey , watch me, install this". Exploits that trigger silent download and install is quite expensive(short-lived) to build compare to human engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beep comes from the un-completion notification - a thing that pops-up even in g-mail if you do not let it finish various in-progress actions.

The redirect may of been done even by a plugin or an active malicious script on your system. Fortinet is an e-mail security appliance and Spamhaus is an e-mail blocklist centralization system - they are not viruses.

Traditional anti-viruses often miss scripts that are designed to mimic normal functionality so I'd recommend you scanning your system with tools like HitmanPro Malware Removal Tool and Malwarebytes.

Comment: Did both Malwarebytes and HitmanPro scans, no threat was found

Here's the virus total scan for part of the url:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/f3516f9c63ddb23ad6b1ef202601c5bec6cc7ea6460be714895d8850ff135d2d/detection

I'm mostly worried if this could have gotten my gmail address, I was logged to 2 at my emails, and changed the password for one of them

I found the beep strange because I never heard it before.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Some scripts steal passwords store in insecure things like outlook and then attempt to login and send spam e-mails. Some of them act as run-once, so if there is no active threat and you changed your password everything should be fine.